# Angular + jQuery produces "Uncaught object" error instead of display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Building new application, using latest stable Angular 1.2.17 and jQuery 1.11.1 versions.
Then I do manual error, like initialising ng-app without any scripts, which should produce error like "No module XXX", but I just see error "Uncaught object".
I've tried other versions, like Angular 1.2.16 + jQuery 2.1.1 and others - same result.

What I do wrong?

// upd

Ubuntu 14, Chrome 35

Comment: uncaught *object*? Please post the exact error message, and your page's markup that reproduces this error message

Comment: Post the code you're using and the exact error message. We can guess all day long what's wrong, but you won't get a reliable answer without something reproducable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found.
It's Chrome's issue, we have to wait about 37 Chrome Canary to being merged into release.
/me went to obtain Chrome Canary

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5568

http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/

https://codereview.chromium.org/271733005/patch/1/10001

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I would have lost many more hours if I hadn't found this link to http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/ explaining that
there is a bug in the Chrome browser API that Angular invokes to show the error to the user. __ 
I installed Firefox to get better error tracing. (Turned out I had an error ***Unknown provider: $routeProvider***, a common error in upgrading Angular 1.0.x > 1.2.x because the ngRoute is moved to the separate angular-resource)