# Angular Uncaught object error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the following error when trying out Angular, why?

**Error:**

```
Uncaught object angular.js:36
(anonymous function) angular.js:36
(anonymous function) angular.js:3745
r angular.js:323
e angular.js:3711
Zb angular.js:3651
Yb.c angular.js:1379
Yb angular.js:1394
Uc angular.js:1307
(anonymous function) angular.js:21163
a angular.js:2445
(anonymous function) angular.js:2716
r angular.js:330
c
```

Simple output below of what is on the page:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<script src="js/apps/campaign.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Campaign has:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular + jQuery produces "Uncaught object" error instead of display it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126713/angular-jquery-produces-uncaught-object-error-instead-of-display-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```